# Why are my TRAINABLE_VARIABLES in Tensorflow so weird?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I've just started my first TF project.
I trained a 4 layer vanilla NN on MNIST.

Then I wanted to display the learned weights,
but weirdly I got way more output than I expected.

I used

```
sess.run(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "my_w1"))
```

where I had previously defined

```
tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer_sizes[i-1], layer_sizes[i]]), name = "my_w1").
```

The problem is, that I expected a 2d array of the shape (784, 500),
but I got a 3d one of the shape (15, 784, 500).

What does the first dimension mean?

Comment: Were you giving it batches of 15 elements in your training process? Maybe something going on with that? I am not sure though.

Comment: I'm not sure. I posted my code here http://text-share.com/view/c5e36fa3

Answer (score 0):

This is your batch size: the number of images you use in each iteration. It comes from this part of the code: `epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)`

Comment: Okay, thank you. But I'm still a little confused. Why do I get different weights after each batch? Especially because they don't seem to converge and vary quite a bit.

Comment: Your weights should change, otherwise you are not training anything at all. The weights should not necessarily converge, your loss function should